# Resize big sprites in good way

Tags: graphics, sprites, pixel

How to resize 2D sprites in the size of like *400px* to *64px* or *32px* in a way that doesn't make it look pixelated and weird?

Comment: No, I haven't. the only thing I have done is to resize it in a pixel art program to the size I want.

Comment: Do you have an example of the sprite you're working with, and the result you're getting so far that you want to improve? For different art styles we might use different techniques.

Comment: Before rescaling: https://ibb.co/kQEpoH         After rescaling: https://ibb.co/nDMr2c

Comment: Most pixel art on the 64 pixel scale & smaller is hand-drawn for that size. Because you have so few pixels to work with, conscious use of the pixel grid is extremely important in these sizes. You'll have a hard time generating good-looking pixel art by downscaling. Does your workflow allow for artist intervention to tune, touch up, and redraw the results, or are you planning to rely solely on scaling algorithms?

Comment: The best I have seen for this sort of problem is to look into Gimp2 for the extension which basically gives you an Ansiotropic filtering effect.  Which will try and approximate as much detail into your reduced texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Photoshop, and you want resize a sprite, the best way to do it is by going to File -> Save for web.

And then play with this:

[image]

On Image Size, put the desired new width and height and play with the Quality, for resizing Pixel Art Sprites I suggest to use "Nearest neighbor". Once you input the desired size and quality you'll be able to preview the output and then save your image.